# input events not getting triggered when use select 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing an issue with ui-select 2 plugin 
When i click an input box i need to do an ajax for getting the values in dropdown 
html

```
<input ng-model="panelData.name" ng-click ="fnChangeName(panelData.designation)" style="width:100%;" ui-select2="oSelect2Designation" required><span></span>
```

But here neither of input events are working i also tried ng-mouseenter,ng-mouseover,ng-change,ng-mouseup and more..
but nothing is working
here is my controller code

```
$scope.fnChangeName = function(designation) {
         $scope.aTpNames.length = 0;
        jobDescriptionService.fnGetTPNames(designation, $scope.practice).then(function(response) {
            for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                $scope.aTpNames.push(response[i].fullname);
            }
        }, function(response) {

        });
    };
```

I have no idea what the issue is

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Could you share more code? Nothing seems to be wrong with your posted code.

Comment: ui-select2 has been deprecated https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2

Comment: show me how is $scope.oSelect2Designation look like. you need to overide 'query function' inside that object scope.